# How to delete the item on checkbox selection and display in the bottom of listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am displaying data in the listview as below.

Header 1
checkbox      item 1 
checkbox      item 2 
checkbox      item 3

header 2 
checkbox  item 4 
checkbox  item 5 
checkbox  item 6

Can i  delete the item on checkbox selection and display the selected items in the bottom of the listview.

I have tried objects.remove(position) and notifydatasetchanged() but it will delete the items no the header.

can anyone please tell me how to approach this problem.

**Code**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.hb.views.PinnedSectionListView.PinnedSectionListAdapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements PinnedSectionListAdapter  {
    MainActivity ctx;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    List<Contact> objects;
    public static final int FIRST = 0;
    public static final int SECOND = 1;

    ListAdapter(MainActivity context, List<Contact> contacts) {
        ctx = context;
        objects = contacts;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    public void refill(List<Contact> events) {
        objects.clear();
        objects.addAll(events);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public Contact getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        if (viewType == FIRST) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                    .getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.title = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvDescr);
                holder.tvprice = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
                holder.checkbox=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
                //CheckBox cbBuy = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            holder.title.setText(getItem(position).getHeader_id());
            holder.tvprice.setText(getItem(position).getName());
            holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);
            holder.checkbox.setTag(position);
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(getItem(position).isChecked());
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        } else if (viewType == SECOND) {
            convertView = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.section, parent, false);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1))
                    .setText(objects.get(position).getName());

        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        String type = objects.get(position).getName();
        if (type.equals("1")) {
            return FIRST;
        } else {
            return SECOND;
        }

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView tvprice;
        CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    Contact getProduct(int position) {
        return ((Contact) getItem(position));
    }

    ArrayList<Contact> getBox() {
        ArrayList<Contact> box = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        for (Contact p : objects) {
            if (p.box)
                box.add(p);

        }
        return box;
    }

    OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckChangList = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {

            getProduct((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).box = isChecked;
            View row = (View) buttonView.getParent();
            if (isChecked) {
                objects.remove(getProduct((Integer)buttonView.getTag()));

                ArrayList<Contact> box = new ArrayList<Contact>();
                Contact c=getProduct((Integer)buttonView.getTag());
                c.box=isChecked;
                ctx.deleteitem(c);


                notifyDataSetChanged();

                row.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_light);
            } else {
                row.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            }
        }
    };


    @Override
    public boolean isItemViewTypePinned(int viewType) {
        if (viewType == SECOND) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You would need to keep track of which checkboxes in your list are associated with which headers, and when that header has no checkboxes under it anymore, remove it too.

Comment: ya i was able to do that but i can do that dynamically like on selection delete the item and how to delete header ?

Comment: You don't seem to have anything that is associating a checkbox item with a header item. They have a name that distinguishes their type, but that doesn't associate that individual type with the items it should be associated with. Because of that, you need to do some logic in your check change listener that says if (getItemViewType(positon -1).equals("SECOND") && getItemViewType(position +1).equals("SECOND")) and if so delete item in position-1 (which would be your header). Not that this is the best way, just off the top of my head.

Comment: ok @zgc7009 will try something like that.